# linq Average within a groupby

Tags: c#, linq

In this sample below I would like to get the Average of the Answer Yes/No  within a groupby. I am trying to get the count of Yes and the count of No and set the Average to PercentYes .

```
PercentYes = g.Average(g.Where(f => f.Answer == "Yes").Count(),g.Where(f => f.Answer == "No").Count())
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/oyx6Ju

error message

```
Compilation error (line 41, col 20): No overload for method 'Average' takes 2 arguments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Average`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average) indeed does not take two arguments.  It doesn't calculate an average of what you pass it, it calculates an average from what you *call it on* (in this case `g`), using an optional argument as a function to pull a specific value from each instance of the collection (each instance of `g`).

You may be over-thinking it.  Not everything needs LINQ.  You don't even want an *average*.  You want a *percent*.  Just divide the "Yes" count by the total.  For example:

```cs
var yesCount = (decimal)g.Count(f => f.Answer == "Yes");
var noCount = (decimal)g.Count(f => f.Answer == "No");
var percentYes = yesCount / (yesCount + noCount);
```

(Note: I'm casting the "count" values to `decimal` to avoid integer division, which would otherwise always result in `0` here.)